# autrace - Does it call auditctl or not?

Tags: audit

The `autrace` [man page summary](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/autrace.8.html) is a little confusing:

> This command deletes all audit rules prior to executing the target program and after executing it. As a safety precaution, it will not run unless all rules are deleted with auditctl prior to use.

The first sentence says `autrace` deletes the audit rules itself. The second sentence says `autrace` checks if any audit rules exist before running. They are contradictory.

The same confusion is seen elsewhere. [How To Use the Linux Auditing System on CentOS 7](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-linux-auditing-system-on-centos-7) states that

> running autrace will remove all custom auditing rules

which confirms the first sentence. The page goes on to explain that `autrace` fails if the audit rules are locked (immutable), which may explain the second sentence.

On the other hand, [SUSE: Analyzing Processes with autrace](https://www.suse.com/documentation/sled10/audit_sp1/data/sec_audit_autrace.html) states one must manually emit `auditctl -D` before running `autrace`.

Another point of contention between the two pages concerns the resulting `autrace.log`: the first page states it:

> looks similar to the standard audit log entries

while the second states it:

> does not look any different from the standard audit log entries.

Are the logs formatted the same or not?

A related issue: the `ausearch` [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/ausearch) states it:

> can query the audit daemon logs

and provides `--input` and `--input-logs` options to query a specific log file (historical, imported, whatever) or the log file specified by `auditd.conf`, respectively. But the `auditd` and `auditd.conf` don't specify the default logging location. [Linux audit – Log files /var/log/audit](https://linux-audit.com/linux-audit-log-files-in-var-log-audit/) states the default location is `/var/log/audit` because that's the default value `auditd.conf` is created with. But that would make the `--input-logs` option pointless. So what is the default audit log location and how is it determined?